# how to add a dynamically created bean in a @PostConstruct in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to add a dynamically created bean when my 'normal' bean gets created. I tried this so far:

```
//generate a health bean dynamically, and register it
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    solrhealth = new SolrHealthIndicator(solr);
    //context.??
}
```

I build a SolrHealthIndicatior bean programatically, as I am not using Spring Solr Data. Now I want it registered so it shows up in /health.

I have my  context wired, but cannot find how to register the newly created bean in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to programatically define your bean by using the `@Bean` annotation within a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Bean
public SolrHealthIndicator solrHealthIndicatior() {
    //you can construct the object however you want
    return new SolrHealthIndicator();
}
```

Then you can just inject it like any other bean(`@Autowired` constructor, field, setter injection, etc.), if there are multiple beans with the same type you can use `@Qualifier` to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@Lookup` annotation.

```
@Component
public class SolrHealthIndicator {

    public SolrHealthIndicator(Solr solr) {

    }
}


public class BeanInQuestion {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        solrHealthIndicator = getHealthIndicatorBean();
    }

    @Lookup
    public SolrHealthIndicator getHealthIndicatorBean() {
        //Spring creates a runtime implementation for this method
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: mmm, not sure I follow. SolrHealthIndicator is a builtin class, I don't need to define it I guess? And then, where do you declare solrHealthIndicator? I guess you need to declare it in some way (annotation or whatever) so that it is registered automatically? Or does annotating the getter with @lookup accomplis that already? thanks

Comment: In that case, you may need to use xml based lookup.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection

Comment: I need to *register* a singleton bean (that I create) when another singleton bean is created by Spring, @lookup does not seem to help  in this if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You want to create a spring bean of type SolrHealthIndicator (which is a lib class) when you create a HealthBean. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the class containing your `@PostConstruct` implement [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html). Then you'd then be able to register your beans programmatically:

```
@Bean
public class MyBean implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    private BeanDefinitionRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("solrHealthIndicator", new SolrHealthIndicator(solr));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, might work, did not try, @Magnus' answer was much simpler

Comment: Ah, yes, most definitely. I thought you had some sort of specific requirement that such that you wanted it to happen on the `PostConstruct` method. @Magnus' answer is definitely the more standard option and the way you should go